What is a safe distance from a power transformer to avoid health risks from EMF exposure?
A nearby power transformation station converts 30,000V to 400V, and I’m concerned about electromagnetic field (EMF) exposure. The World Health Organization (WHO) states that while research is ongoing, long-term exposure to high EMF levels may be linked to certain health risks, particularly childhood leukemia. If the EMF at the station’s outer wall is around 150 µT, how far would I need to be for the EMF to drop below 0.25 µT, which I understand is a safer level?
Can you suggest a practical, safe distance from the station to avoid health risks? Also, I would appreciate to gain knowledge on typical background exposure, which one is subjected to anyways.

Here is some more info that may help you find your comfort level.   IDK why you're focusing specifically on the magnetic field from a transformer, but just going with the question 1 meter roughly should do it.  I used the linked article to guide that guess without judging any aspect of the question.   In other words, just don't put your bed touching the transformer.  Live in your house and it will be some other thing that kills you, not this.

@jay613 Thank you for sharing. FYI, the link appears to have a typo.

https://www.who.int/news-room/questions-and-answers/item/radiation-electromagnetic-fields

Levels
EMF drops at a square of the distance, so its rapid. If you are outside its fenced area, you are safe.  If you are worried then buy a meter to measure it.
Harm
I have been following this since it was first reported in 1975ish by a farmer that piglets were being born defective on his farm. Many studies have been done. None of them have found correlation between EMF level and harm.
There was one Nordic study that found a link between Static Electricity and harm.  However, it is being ignored by the power companies.
Concern
You should be more concerned about the following

Living under a power line
Extended use of a hair dryer
Sleeping with the phone under your pillow
Talking with the phone on your ear for more that 10s of minutes


Driving with your phone.  Walking down the stairs with your phone.  Walking down the stairs with a large transformer.  :⁠-⁠). Sleeping with a transformer under your pillow.

In my country (Bulgaria) it is a rather common occurence a transformer building with few residental apartments either on the top or on the side of the big transformer halls. Communism, if you wonder why. The apartments were generally given to people employed in various electrical grid related jobs (and even to managers thereof - some locations are rather attractive).
In short, we do have maybe 1000 people living decades of their everyday lives, raising kids, etc... separated by a single masonry or concrete wall from the big big transformers.
As far as I know, no statistically significant health risk is identified.
(Yes, the transformer hum is somewhat audible at night.)
